# Wordpress blog snippet on HTML web page

Tags: wordpress

Trying to figure out if there is a way to take a snippet of a wordpress blog, same site, same hosting, and plug that into a pure HTML page.

Example... I want to show the title of the blog, and first 150 characters. With a link to ..."read more" which would take the visitor to the actual blog.

Widget? or custom type of coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that WordPress exposes blog output to other applications is through the RSS feed.

It is often available by URL at 
"http:// your-Wordpress-Root-URL.com/ feed".

You can use that URL in a 3rd-party widget that you use via HTML/JS on any HTML page.
They'll give you the code snippet to drop in your page.
And they'll have different options to customize things like the number of blog entries to show, and the length to preview - as you mentioned.

I'll paste a couple links to start with, and you can easily search for more online with something like "RSS feed widget" in google.

- https://www.rssinclude.com
- http://www.webrss.com/
- http://www.rssfeedwidget.com/